# Inserting a GROUP BY result into another table

Tags: sql, mysql

I was migrating a field to a new table.  The new table has three fields.  What I tried was

```
INSERT INTO foo VALUES ('', (SELECT bar FROM baz GROUP BY bar), '');
```

This resulted in an error due to multiple rows resulting from the select.

What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want something like:

```
INSERT INTO foo (col1name, col2name, col3name)
    SELECT '', bar, ''
    FROM baz
    GROUP BY bar
```

Answer (score 8):

Or if I'm understanding you correctly and you want one entry in the new table for every distinct bar value in the old table I think this makes that a bit clearer.

```
INSERT INTO foo (col2name) SELECT DISTINCT bar FROM baz
```

The execution plan and performance should be similiar

Comment: Neat and elegant solution

Answer (score 4):

You can try:

```
INSERT INTO foo 
SELECT '',bar,'' FROM baz GROUP BY bar
```

Answer (score 4):

```
INSERT INTO foo (fieldName1,fieldName2,fieldName3) 
    SELECT '',bar,'' FROM baz GROUP BY bar
```

Answer (score 4):

Going with Michael's answer, another possibility would be

```
INSERT INTO foo (col2name) SELECT bar FROM baz GROUP BY bar
```

where col1 and col3 are defined to have a default of the empty string.

Answer (score 0):

insert into personinsure (**column names**)
select (**column names**) from personinsure
where yearmonth_fld=202205 and id_fld in (select max(id_fld) from personinsure
where yearmonth_fld=202205
group by personId )

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).